# Writing in sub directory - Azure Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my Data flow, the sink is ADLS.
My source files are present in SoureDump/Data  and I am reading from path SoureDump/Data. I am doing few transformations and I am trying write the output files into SoureDump/Rawzone.
Output file name is created from the data.
When I trigger the pipeline, the output files are generated as expected but are written in the parent directory SoureDump.

My work:

[image]

[image]

DataSet screenshot

[image: DataSet screenshot]

Please let me know if I have given anything wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As data in column" defaults back to your dataset container object. Check the info bubble next to the column name field:

[image]

Just set your target folder with a Derived Column prior to your sink and append the value like this:

tgt_file_name_w_path = '/mypath/output/'+tgt_file_name

Then use tgt_file_name_w_path instead in your column with file name property.